# Sequel::DatabaseError - PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR: argument of AND must be type boolean, not type integer

Tags: ruby, postgresql, sequel

I don't understand why this error:

```
Sequel::DatabaseError - PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  argument of AND must be type boolean, not type integer
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM "grupos" WHERE (("idGrupo" = 1) AND "idGrupo")...
```

My Sequel query is:

```
#@grupo = DB["SELECT * FROM grupos WHERE idGrupo = #{params[:num]}"]
@grupo = DB[:grupos].where(:idGrupo => params[:num].to_i)
```

Comment: Are you sure that `where` call is the one producing that query?

Comment: If I write: `@grupo = DB[:grupos]` the query result is `SELECT * FROM "grupos" WHERE "idGrupo" LIMIT 1`. I don't understand why.

Comment: The query should be `SELECT * FROM "grupos"`, without `idGrupo`.

Comment: Right, just throwing an integer into the WHERE clause like that doesn't make any sense at all with PostgreSQL. I don't know Sequel that well so I'm not sure why it would be doing that. Does it do that sort of thing with every table or is it just `grupos`?

Comment: So what's special about how `grupos` is set up in Sequel? Does it happen when you `where(:idGrupo => 6)` or only with `where(:idGrupo => 1)`?

Comment: This happens in all tables with the primary key, when I try `where(:id => 6)`

Comment: Did you create your tables properly? What you're doing seems to be working fine for me.

Comment: It's solved. I think the problem was that I had a `puts` after the query, and the program interpreted it as an attribute. Thanks for all!